# What is the korn typset option -t (tag) used for?

Tags: shell, ksh, typeset

I was reading about the Korn [typeset command](http://www.docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90046/ch23s06.html?btnPrev=%AB%A0prev) and discovered the `-t` option adds a tag, but I can't figure out what it's used for.  Does anyone have an example?

> -t
>   Tags the name. Tags are user definable and have no special meaning to the shell.

Comment: I though everyone was using only bash these days :o)

Comment: @Maxwell, we wish, but not the case, there are tons of old farts using ksh where i work, annoying!

Comment: @Maxwell a lot of businesses, especially running unix, are still standardized on Kshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also wondered this, and discovered it is useless, you can run

```
typeset +t
```

to return all the 'tagged' variables, if you wanted to..

http://www.shelldorado.com/search/search-swish.cgi

here they use it to define a set of allowed variables.